# Selecting person and all his specialties with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of primary keys that point to a `Persons` table.

```
List<string> personKeys;
```

I also have a table that keeps specialites of each person, a person may have many specialties, may have one or may have no specialty at all.
So that table (PersonSpecialties) will have a sample schema like

```
PersonSpecialty_K, Person_K, SpecialtyName
```

I want to pass in that personKeys list and query the database and get a list or dictionary of each person and his specialties.
I am having trouble writing this query.

```
var personAndSpecialties = (from ps in this.context.PersonSpecialties 
    where personKeys.Contains(ps.Person_K) select WHAT? )
```

Comment: So you want: `Dictionary<Person, SpecialtyName>` right?

Comment: @CodingGorilla  yes, something like that, so later I can loop through them and say ok this person, these specialties ,etcc..

Comment: `select WHAT? ` Select an anonymous type with appropriate properties. Then you can map it to your CLR type if you have one.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan but what happens when there is more than one specialty for one person ? I get confused in that part.

Comment: Then you can have two properties in your anonymous type  - Person of Person type and PersonSpecialties of LIst<PersonSpecialtiy> type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using [`group by`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386922(v=vs.100).aspx)?

```
var personAndSpecialties = (from ps in this.context.PersonSpecialties 
                               where personeys.Contains(ps.Person_K)
                               group ps.SpecialtyName by ps.Person_K)
```

I have no SQL to test right now but this may work.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
var personAndSpecialties = (
    from p in this.Context.Person
        join ps in PersonSpecialties on p.Person_K equals ps.Person_K into joined
    from ps in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where personKeys.Contains(p.Person_K) select p, psd );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create another class called PersonSpecialtyViewModel

```
public class PersonSpecialtyViewModel
{
    public Person        Person         {get; set;}
    public SpecialtyName SpecialtyName  {get; set;}
}
```

and you query may be something like that

```
var personAndSpecialties = (from ps in this.context.PersonSpecialties 
where personKeys.Contains(ps.Person_K) select new  PersonSpecialtyViewModel() { Person = ps.Person, SpecialtyName = ps.SpecialtyName }).ToList();
```

Comment: ok so if the person has three specialties, I will have three things in my class list?  like (P1, Radiology) , (P1, Dentistry) , (P1, Skin care)

Comment: public SpecialtyName {get; set;}  ?  what is the datatype here?

Comment: oh sorry, i corrected my answer. and yes just like you said for one person that have 3 specialties you will get a collection that contains 3 elements